# Code is not finding the right variance

Tags: java, variance

I am writing code for my AP Computer Science class and I need to find the variance of a group of numbers. For those of you who dont know how to find variance it is the sum of the squares of the differences of the values from the average all divided by 1 less then length. To make this more understandable heres an example. If you had the data {1, 5, 8, 7, 2, 7}, then the average would be 6. You variance would then be [(1-6)^2 + (5-6)^2 + (8-6)^2 + (7-6)^2 + (2-6)^2 + (7-6)^2]/5 = 8.4. So here is the method.

```
public static double variance(int[] data) {
    int sum = 0;
    double average;

    for (int i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + data[i];
    }
    average = (double)sum/data.length;

    for (int i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i] = data[i] - (int)average^2;
    }

    int add = 0;
    for (int d : data)
        add += d;
    add = add/data.length-1;
    return add;
    }
}
```

I am not allowed to change data from an int array, I have no clue why I am getting the wrong variance, please help!

Comment: What's this `add=add/data.length-1;`? Some integer division perchance? Is that wanted?

Comment: "all divided by 1 less then length"

Comment: You have to use floats for accurate division; using an int causes the result to be rounded down to an integer. In your given example, your result would never be '8.4' but, rather, '8', if you used an int

Answer (score 6):

Your most obvious problem is here:

`average^2`

The `^` operator is not exponentiation. It is [bitwise XOR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Use:

```
Math.pow(average, 2)
```

or

```
average * average
```

Also,

1. You are supposed to square the deviation, not the average.
2. Don't do `(int)` cast
3. `add/data.length-1` is wrong
4. Modifying the `data` array is unnecessary.

Adding in a bit of clean up,

```
public static double variance(int[] data) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int datum : data) {
        sum += datum;
    } 
    double average = (double)sum / data.length;

    double devianceSum = 0;
    for (int datum : data) {
        devianceSum += Math.pow(datum - average, 2);
    }
    return devianceSum / data.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few points in your code where your calculations lose precision, which is likely causing your answer to be far off from what you expect. As mentioned, you have to use [`Math.pow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) in Java for exponentiation. But that needs to be applied to the difference of each value and the average, not just the average itself. Essentially, you need parentheses `(a-b)^2` not `a - b^2` (in math syntax). You should also be using `double` as your data-type throughout, rather than `int`.

```
public static double variance(int[] data) {
    double sum = 0;
    double average;
    double[] deviations = new int[data.length];

    for (int i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        sum += data[i];
    }
    average = sum/data.length;

    for (int i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        deviations[i] = Math.pow(data[i] - average, 2);
    }

    double result = 0;
    for (Double d : deviations)
        result += d;

    result = result/data.length-1;

    return result;
}
```